# Web analytics platform that can run on a load-balanced server cluster?

Tags: web-analytics, matomo, web-analytics-tools

I'm using Piwik for my web-analytics, and recently I've discovered PHPFog/CloudControl as hosting providers that set up a load balanced, fully managed server for your applications to run on. Piwik requires certain directories to be writable in order to set configuration files, and this prevents me from using load-balancing to enhance my piwik response times.

Does anyone know of an analytics package like piwik (or maybe a different version of piwik) that supports load balancing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Piwik supports load balancing! See the doc at: http://piwik.org/faq/new-to-piwik/#faq_134

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see that before.